# Array, Inheritance, Method?

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

why do i have an error?

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class LabWork1 {
    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int lengthOfList = 10;
    public static int [] gradeList = new int[lengthOfList];
    public static int search;

    class getGrades{//error here
        for(int i = 0 ; i < lengthOfList ; i++){
            System.out.print("Enter your grade: ");
            gradeList[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
    class outputList{//error here
        for(int i = 0 ; i < lengthOfList ; i++){
            System.out.print(gradeList[i] + " ");
        }
    }
    class searchForGrade{//error here
        for(int i = 0 ; i < lengthOfList ; i++){
            if(gradeList[i] == search){
                System.out.println(gradeList[i] + " is located in index " +     i);
            }
            else if(gradeList[i] != search){
                System.out.println("Grade is not in index " + i);
            }
        }
    }
    class replaceGrade{//error here
        for(int i = 0 ; i < lengthOfList ; i++){
            if(gradeList[i] == search){
                System.out.println("Enter another grade: ");
                gradeList[i] = input.nextInt();
            }
            else if(gradeList[i] != search){
                    System.out.println("Grade is not in index " + i);
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("Enter the length of the list: ");
        lengthOfList = input.nextInt();

        new getGrades();
        new outputList();

        System.out.println("Enter the grade that you want to search: ");
        search = input.nextInt();
        new searchForGrade();

        new outputList();

        System.out.println("Enter the grade that you want to replace: ");
        search = input.nextInt();
        new replaceGrade();

        new outputList();
    }
}//error here
```

this program asks the user to input the length of the array(numbers of grades) then asks for the grades, then search for a grade inputed(ex. user enters 10 program looks for 10 in array list), then ask the user for a grade to replace, replace the grade with the new grade inputed by the user. the list of the array(grades) should be shown every other method.

after doing some changes i still got an error

```
     import java.util.*;

  public class LabWork1 {
public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
public static int lengthOfList = 10;
public static int [] gradeList = new int[lengthOfList];
public static int search;

public void getGrades{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < lengthOfList ; i++){
        System.out.print("Enter your grade: ");
        gradeList[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
}
public void outputList{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < lengthOfList ; i++){
        System.out.print(gradeList[i] + " ");
    }
}
public void searchForGrade{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < lengthOfList ; i++){
        if(gradeList[i] == search){
            System.out.println(gradeList[i] + " is located in index " + i);
        }
        else if(gradeList[i] != search){
            System.out.println("Grade is not in index " + i);
        }
    }
}
public void replaceGrade{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < lengthOfList ; i++){
        if(gradeList[i] == search){
            System.out.println("Enter another grade: ");
            gradeList[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        else if(gradeList[i] != search){
            System.out.println("Grade is not in index " + i);
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("Enter the length of the list: ");
    lengthOfList = input.nextInt();

    LabWork1 labwork = new LabWork1();
    labwork.getGrades();
    labwork.outputList();

    System.out.println("Enter the grade that you want to search: ");
    search = input.nextInt();
    labwork.searchForGrade();

    labwork.outputList();

    System.out.println("Enter the grade that you want to replace: ");
    search = input.nextInt();
    labwork.replaceGrade();

    labwork.outputList();
}
```

}

thank you so much guys i just added () to every method and now its working!

```
 import java.util.*;

public class LabWork1 {
public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
public static int lengthOfList = 10;
public static int [] gradeList = new int[lengthOfList];
public static int search;

public void getGrades(){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < lengthOfList ; i++){
        System.out.print("Enter your grade: ");
        gradeList[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
}
public void outputList(){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < lengthOfList ; i++){
        System.out.print(gradeList[i] + " ");
    }
}
public void searchForGrade(){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < lengthOfList ; i++){
        if(gradeList[i] == search){
            System.out.println(gradeList[i] + " is located in index " + i);
        }
        else if(gradeList[i] != search){
            System.out.println("Grade is not in index " + i);
        }
    }
}
public void replaceGrade(){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < lengthOfList ; i++){
        if(gradeList[i] == search){
            System.out.println("Enter another grade: ");
            gradeList[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        else if(gradeList[i] != search){
            System.out.println("Grade is not in index " + i);
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("Enter the length of the list: ");
    lengthOfList = input.nextInt();

    LabWork1 labwork = new LabWork1();
    labwork.getGrades();
    labwork.outputList();

    System.out.println("Enter the grade that you want to search: ");
    search = input.nextInt();
    labwork.searchForGrade();

    labwork.outputList();

    System.out.println("Enter the grade that you want to replace: ");
    search = input.nextInt();
    labwork.replaceGrade();

    labwork.outputList();
}
```

}

Comment: Because you're trying to run code in class declaration bodies instead of in methods or initialization blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're declaring a new class instead of method

try to change them like this one:

```
public void getGrades() {
    //your code.
}
```

instead of

```
class getGrades{//error here
    //your code.
}
```

Also You need to remove the new keyword from calling the methods, you can call them like thes:

```
LabWork1 labwork = new LabWork1();
labwork.getGrades();
```

All about [classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/) and [methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) in java.

Comment: i changed all the class to public void but i got a new error

Comment: You should remove the `new` keyword too from method call. And make the methods static too. Read the methods/classes pages!

Comment: @MarcoAcierno thanks for hint, user3406298 see my updates above.

Comment: after addingLabWork1 labwork = new LabWork1();
labwork. to everything still got an error

Answer (score 0):

You get errors because you've put code in bodies of nested classes outside of any methods. Then inside main method you call constructors of nested classes. I think you should use normal methods instead of nested classes as suggested by Salah. Also, remember to remove "new" keywords.

Just curious, is Java your first programming language or have you taken this from some other language?

Comment: this is my first programming language.